# high level design question in Reactjs: Passing upload file data between components before sending to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

**Application:**
I have an upload portal which has three components to it - bare in mind I have not configured all components to work yet, I have only built a rough layout of the UI.

1. The first component is where the user selects the file - as seen in image A
2. The second component is a confirmation screen where the certain sets of data from the file is laid out for the user to confirm - as seen in image B
3. The third and final component is just a screen showing progress of upload and a final message

**The Issue/Question**:

When the user selects the file for the dropzone (Component A) and clicks "Next" or "Send" (whichever wording I use). It will go to Component B - to confirm if values are correct. 
Now Should I just pass the data as props or using redux when going from component A to B?

**Why I ask this question**

I am wondering about security. How can I make sure the data does not get "changed" between Component A and by the time it arrives in Component C 
(final component where it gets uploaded after confirmation)?

I will validate front-end before sending to back-end - back-end will reside on AWS API Gateway using Node.js. On the back-end I will validate before it hits the DB.

Is what I am dong enough? Is there anything else I should consider when it moves as a prop from Component A to Component C?

**Component A**

[image]

**Component B**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any security issues you would have sending data from one component to another.

What I would recommend you is not to use Redux for this as you would be complicating things more than necesary.

I might suggest that you have a parent component which acts as wrapper for component A and B.

So in code would be something like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {file ? <ComponentB /> : <ComponentA />} // If there is a file, render B (which is the last step)
    </div>

  )
}
```

This component is just a vague code of how it would be implemented.

Comment: great. Yes I still need to refactor a few things but thanks for this!